# Ionic on Codepen: how to start a new pen and get Ionic support

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, cordova

There are many Codepen examples for Ionic
http://codepen.io/ionic/public-list/

But how can I start a new pen and get Ionic support

If I try to start one from scratch (as in put up some code snippets from docs), Ionic doesn't work:
http://codepen.io/adaptivedev/pen/gFnyr

I also tried with the "todo" tutorial code (including the head tag including .css link, which Codepen says isn't necessary)
http://codepen.io/adaptivedev/pen/gFnyr

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at some of the examples you can see they are linking css and js files

```
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js">
```

That would be the bext option. If not, you can link those files by clicking on the little cog icons (under CSS/JS) and adding the link(s) where indicated.